# Node.js how to download webp image

Tags: node.js, image, httprequest, webp

It´s very easy to download images via the request module. But this is only working for me when then end of the url contains .jpg or .png

But how can you download as example this image?
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/VpoWDgQ2I_RlTNM1Srlo5Q0VQglr-gdbzJ48TwYRXM2U4iF75PMrv76rBiu5c3l1UJs=s180-rw

Does anybody know a method to download the image as .jpg?

Comment: That's not base64. It's [webp](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/). What you appear to be looking for is MIME detection instead of relying on a `.jpg` or `.png` on the extension name of the resource. You probably should not be phrasing a question on the presumption that this is base64 when it is not, since the approaches are completely different.

Comment: Sorry I didn´t know that. Do you know how you can download this image?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on [howtogeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/325864/how-to-save-googles-webp-images-as-jpeg-or-png/)

"Click the URL bar, delete the last three characters in the address (the “-rw”), and then press “Enter.” The same image will be displayed again, but this time it’s rendered in its original format, usually JPEG or PNG."